# Best way to program a cost function (associate function - value)

Tags: haskell, search, pattern-matching

I am trying to program a cost function in Haskell, but it seems I overestimated the capabilities of patter matching. This is the code I have already defined:

```
-- Directions for the movement
data Direction = North | East | West | South deriving (Show, Eq)

-- An `Action` gets a Coord and returns another Coord if possible
type Action = Coord -> Maybe Coord

-- Move function; `move North` is an Action
move :: Direction -> Action
move d (x, y) = ...
```

My main problem is that now I have to define a `Cost` function such that:

```
type Cost = Coord -> Action -> Double
```

In case I wanted to have a simple cost function that only checks the direction to return a cost, the first idea that came to my mind was taking advantage of pattern matching, but this is invalid syntax (and to be honest, it seems quite fair):

```
mazeCost :: Cost
mazeCost (x, y) (move East) = 3
mazeCost (x, y) (move West) = 5
-- ... And on and on
```

My current solution involves computing the destination state and comparing that to the result of each action to check if that is the function that is being passed as an argument, but that seems hacky, not super brief and I think that maybe there is a much better way to do it in Haskell:

```
mazeCost :: Cost
mazeCost coord action
  | destination == east   = 1
  | destination == west   = 2
  | destination == north  = 3
  | destination == south  = 0
  where destination = action coord
        east  = move East  coord
        west  = move West  coord
        south = move South coord
        north = move North coord
```

Is there a better way to associate a function (`Coord -> Direction -> Maybe Coord`) with a cost value (`Double`)? This is a minimal example I tried to write, if there are any inconsistencies in the example code or something is not clear, please ask.

Comment: What if `destination` is not one of the four cardinal directions?  E.g. if it is a composition of `move`s?

Comment: Why  represent the action by the result of the move, rather than the chosen direction, which would allow you to pattern match?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia that's exactly what I want to do, but what I currently pass to the function is the already partially-applied function, like `move East`. That is what I am trying to pattern match, but I don't know the syntax to "unpack" those values

Comment: Change it to `type Action = Coord -> Maybe (Coord, Double)`?

Comment: You can't "unpack" a partially applied function. My point is that maybe you should take a step back and redesign your types to fit your application better.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you just need `ViewPatterns`

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns ... #-}
...
move ((x,y), d) = ... Just (d,...) ...

moveCost = curry moveCost' where
    moveCost' (move -> Just (East, (x,y))) = ...
    moveCost' (move -> Just (West, (x,y))) = ...
```

Note that we changed the type of `move` here. View patterns only work with single argument functions that return a pattern we can actually match on, so it has to be passed `((x,y),d)` as a tuple, which means `moveCost'` must accept a tuple, but we can just curry it with a wrapper function.

Comment: I don't see how that would work. `move` does not give a `Maybe Direction`.

Comment: We can tuple the coordinate returned with the initial direction, it was just a simple example, but I'll add it in.

Answer (score 0):

`Cost` takes a `Coord` and an `Action`. However, since actions need a coord and a direction and there's no direction in scope, you can't actually use the action. You need to apply the action to a coordinate *and* a direction in order to get a value. So the only implementations of `mazeCost` are ones that ignore the action entirely, which is not what you want.

However, if you had a direction in scope somehow then you could apply it (and the coord) to the action. One way to do this is through currying. A function `Direction -> Cost`is a function that takes a direction and gives a cost function *for that direction*.

```
mazeCost :: Direction -> Cost
mazeCost dir coord act = case act coord dir of
  Just (x', y') -> 0 -- or whatever the cost is
  Nothing -> 0 -- or whatever the cost is
```

I think this is a nice illustration of the idea that partial application is similar to introducing a closure: `mazeCost East` is a function that closes over the `Direction` `East` and gives a `Cost` for that direction.

I should also note that I don't see how your proposed solution can typecheck. If `type Action = Coord -> Direction -> Maybe Coord`, which you did not specify, then the expression `action coord` is a function of type `Direction -> Maybe Coord`, and not a 'destination'. If I have misunderstood and it does typecheck then it is still a partial function that will cause a runtime error if the action is not equivalent to a simple `move` in one of the `Direction`s, as luqui implied.

Comment: You are completely right about the code, it was not type checking because I made a mistake trying to create the minimal example; I edited the question to correct it. The thing is that an action would be `move South`, for example, and that is what is being passed to `mazeCost`; is there a way to "unpack" that argument so I can pattern-match or evaluate the `Direction` somehow?